# How do I set up a required field validator to not allow a string with just whitespace

Tags: angular, angular-material

Say I have an Angular Reactive form

```
this.setupForm = fb.group({
  "name": ['John Smith', Validators.required]
});
```

and I have a form field

```
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
            <input type="text" matInput formControlName="name" />
            <mat-error *ngIf="name.invalid">A name is required</mat-error>

        </mat-form-field>
```

In this scenario, the form field name is invalid when it does not have a value. However it will allow a string with just whitespace.

How do I set up a validator on the formfield so that it is required field and the value cannot be just blankspace?

Comment: you can also add a pattern to your input: for example pattern="\s*(\S\s*){10,}", to have at leat 10 non space characters

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a custom validator. But you can also incorporate with the help of little tweaking like below:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="name.invalid && !!name.value && !!name.value.trim()">A name is required</mat-error>.
```

Just check the form control value and its trimmed value.

Answer (score 0):

What about a custom validator ?

```
export function noWhiteSpaceValidator(): (control: AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors {
  return control => !(!!control.value && !!control.value.trim()) ? { whiteSpace: true } : null;
}
```

And :

```
"name": ['John Smith', [Validators.required, noWhiteSpaceValidator]]
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, But I followed that same concept and created my own custom validator (see my answer)

Comment: Indeed, it should have been: `!(!!control.value && !!control.value.trim())`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use pattern validation.

```
firstName: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^[A-z]*$/)]]
```

Comment: that regex invalidates any string with a whitespace. So it'll pick up " " but it'll also pick up "John Smith".

Answer (score 0):

This custom validator seems to work

```
export function NoWhitespaceValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
  var val = control.value;

  if(val.trim() == ''){
    return { nowhitespace: true}
  }
  else
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Add in form field

```
  "name": ['', [Validators.compose([Validators.required, NoWhitespaceValidator])]]
```